# Not visible TabItems if TabControl-Items are located left

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have an application with a TabControl on it. The TabItems for this TabControl are created dynamically while the application is running.

The xaml-code to create the TabControl is:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tcTabs" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" TabStripPlacement="Left"/>
```

If I set the `TabStripPlacement` to Top I can see all TabItems. But in my case, where the `TabStripPlacement` is set to Left, it may occure that the TabItems are displayed outside the bounds of the application.

Is there an opportunity to get something like a scrollviewer or something else, where I can scroll to not visible TabItems? Or just set the TabItems in two or more columns on the left-border.

Comment: You'd have to change the `ControlTemplate` for the `TabControl`. Is it something that you're comfortable with?

Comment: @Tomtom Its not that hard to do. Here's an example of a `TabControl` template from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx (I'm not sure if it's the exact one used, but it should be close). Just copy it and edit it so the `TabItems` are drawn within your boundaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [XAMLeLi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/586553/xameli) already mentioned

you should use `ControlTemplate` for the `TabControl`

here is the working example ([here is the Original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690742/1993545))

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Height="60">
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  >
                    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Margin="2,2,2,0" IsItemsHost="true" />
                </ScrollViewer>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
    <TabItem Header="Visible" >
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Visible"/>
    <TabItem Header="Visible"/>
    <TabItem Header="inv" Background="Red">
        <Button Content="blubb"></Button>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="inv"/>
    <TabItem Header="inv"/>
    <TabItem Header="inv"/>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: This template will work but will create layout and usability issues - the stack panel will cause the content of a tab item to take the width that it requires (not more and not less). The scroll bar will be shown between the items and the content - this is not standard.

Comment: @XAMeLi so how would you improve my solution?

Comment: First, there's a need for a Template of scroll viewer similar to the one used by `MenuItem` where the scroll buttons are at top and bottom (requires style for `RepeatButton` and, at least, a Template for `ScrollViewer`). Then, `ItemsPanel` of the tab control should be set to `StackPanel` (or `VirtualizingStackPanel`) and in the template adding the scroll viewer with `ItemsPresenter` as its child. There are other considerations and decisions to make (like max width of items). All this is too long for me to write explicitly, that's why I asked the OP how comfortable he is with templating.

Comment: @XAMeLi nice to know i will implement your sugestion maybe i need it later at work