# how to maintain the Width of tabItems should be equal in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, width, tabcontrol, tabitem

how to maintain the width of the tabItems should be equal if i open multiple tabItems. know i am not getting this thing. i tried the following code

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="stretch"
```

i used the above code but it is not working. but i am getting like this

[image]

for tabcontrol i write the following code

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl1" Margin="175,44,0,0"  >

            <Grid></Grid>
    </TabControl>
```

tabItems will dynamically adding to the Tabcontrol

```
TabItem tabitem2 = new TabItem();
        Page2 pgobj1 = new Page2();
        Frame tabframe1 = new Frame();
        tabframe1.Content = pgobj1;
        tabitem2.Header = "Tab 2Tab 2Tab 3";
        tabitem2.Width = 300;
        tabitem2.Content = tabframe1;          
        tabControl1.Items.Add(tabitem2);
        tabitem2.IsSelected = true;
```

i don't want those spaces in between the tabItems. and they automatically resize if more number of tabs are opened. kindly help me out in this.

After removing the Hardcoded width property

[image]
 it comes like this

Comment: Post relevant XAML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *hardcoded width* you are setting on TabItem. No need to set that, TabItem will automatically adjust its width base on header content.

```
tabitem2.Width = 300; // Remove this line
```

---

If you want items to come in single line and scroll using ScrollViewer, you need to modify Template of TabControl like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5690742/632337). I am posting the code from there for the sake of completeness of answer:

```
    <TabControl Name="tabControl1">
        <TabControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                          Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          Margin="2,2,2,0"
                          IsItemsHost="true"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding 
                                                            SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </TabControl.Template>
    </TabControl>
```

Also check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944413/632337).

Comment: if i remove that line it is going to new line. how to restrict that one

Comment: Which line going to next line?

Comment: If actual window size can't fit tabItems, they are moved like you posted in snapshot. That's how even tabItems works in Windows. Isn't that you required?

Comment: can you tell mehow to restrict tabControl to one line

Comment: What about tabItems which can't be accommodated? What you want to do with those tabItems?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44506/discussion-between-pallavi-and-rohit-vats)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want that all tab items should have equal width. You can achieve that by wrapping each tab item header inside a `Grid` with a `ColumnDefinition` that uses a `SharedSizeGroup`. Furthermore, you must mark the `TabControl` like this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

The following code shows how to set the `Header` property programmatically:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition
    {
        SharedSizeGroup = "MySharedSizedGroupName",
        Width = new GridLength(1.0, GridUnitType.Auto)
    });
grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock{Text="Tab 5"});
tabitem2.Header = grid;
```

**EDIT**: And one other point: I think the `<Grid></Grid>` you have added as a child to the `TabControl` is unnecessary, because it creates that empty tab on the left side in the first tab row.

Comment: can you tell how to restrict tabcontrol to one line

Comment: @Pallavi: You need to add a left and right scroller to the tab panel. This web page shows an example: http://rickdoes.net/post/2009/11/06/WPF-Single-Row-Tab-Control.aspx .