# Make active tab visible in scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a lot of tabs in my tabcontrol, so I used the solution from [want to make scrollable tabs for a tabcontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690594/want-to-make-scrollable-tabs-for-a-tabcontrol).
The problem is that in my window I have buttons Previous-Next, that change active tab. So I want to scrollviewer to move automatically to active tab. It is possible to make by using `BringIntoView()` method of a `FrameworkElement`. But how can I implement it in my case?

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `BringIntoView`?

Comment: @Sheridan Just didn't know how and where to call it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go, I solved the issue by creating an attached behavior ([Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011))

if your template resembles as in the link you've posted

add the following style with the binding the attached property `ScrollHelper.SelectScroll` to `IsSelected` of the tab item

```
    <TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
                <Setter Property="l:ScrollHelper.SelectScroll"
                        Value="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        ...
    </TabControl>
```

behavior class

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    class ScrollHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static bool GetSelectScroll(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(SelectScrollProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectScroll(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectScrollProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectScroll.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectScrollProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectScroll", typeof(bool), typeof(ScrollHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSelectScroll));


        private static void OnSelectScroll(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem tab = d as TabItem;
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                tab.BringIntoView();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

upon change of the property it will invoke `BringIntoView()` method which will pull the tab into view hence scrollviewer will scroll to the tab

you may choose to rename the property or the class as per your liking, I simply chose a random name what came to my mind.