# Placement/Alignment of TabItem headers inside of a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs

When there are too many tabs open in my application for tab headers to fit in one row, `TabItem` headers are separated in two rows. This looks really ugly if I have fixed `TabItem` width.

[image]

I would like them to be aligned left or right in that situation.

I've tried:
`TabControl HorizontalAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment`,
`TabPanel HorizontalAlignment`,
`TabItem HorizontalAlignment`

Comment: Some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690594/want-to-make-scrollable-tabs-for-a-tabcontrol